# jQuery tooltip overlaps image

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I'm using jQuery tooltip but it overlaps images on the page. Is there anyway I can stop this behavior.

```
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="box">
<p class="info">
Some text in tooltip
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.tooltip { position: absolute; z-index: 500; width: 240px; }
.tooltip .box { float: left; background: #4b8aa2; width: 199px; border-radius: 2px; -moz-border-radius: 2px; padding: 10px 15px; }
.tooltip .box p.info { color: #fff; font-size: 1.2em; line-height: 1.2em; }
```

Thanks

Comment: make a demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qLfzw/7/

Comment: remote the position relative from .inner.. Is this you want?